# How to detect mouse click on ellipse drawn in pyside?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qwidget, qgraphicsview

I am using `QPainter` within a `QWidget` to draw a bunch of ellipses on a black background as follows:

```
paint = QPainter()
paint.begin(self)

paint.setBrush(Qt.black)
paint.drawRect(event.rect())

brush = ...
paint.setBrush(brush)
paint.drawEllipse(center, rad, rad)
```

After a bunch of ellipses were drawn, and then I want to detect a mouse click on one of such an existing ellipse. I did not find any obvious in the documentation for `QPainter`.

In case there is something else to be used instead of `QPainter`, please provide an example that shows my above example in the other framework.

Comment: You mean this code is put into the paintEvent or something similar? Could you not set a boolean variable in the mouse click event which in turns calls update on the widget, which will trigger the corresponding event run, which will check against the boolean variable and if it is set, it will draw the ellipse? How does that sound?

Comment: I want the ellipses drawn in any way. Independent of mouse clicks. But when I click on one of the ellipses, I want a method been called.

Comment: OK, I get it, but I do not understand why you post another issue at the end. That does not seem to be relevant to the main question. Also, you have a typo in `classses`.

Comment: I have updated and clearified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to detect the custom area yourself as follows:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    ''' You will have to implement the contain algorithm yourself'''
    if sel.fo(even.pos()):
        self.myMethod()
```

QGraphicsEllipseItem.contains()

Alternatively, you could look into the `QGraphicsEllipseItem` because it has the [contains-logic implemented and offered](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsellipseitem.html#contains).

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if self.contains(event.pos()):
        self.myMethod()
```

and you create your object with the corresponding parameters:

```
scene = QGraphicsScene()
ellipseItem = MyGraphicsEllipseItem(centerx, centery, rad, rad)
scene.addItem(ellipseItem)

view = QGraphicsView(scene)
view.show()

scene.setBackgroundBrush(Qt.black)
```

Comment: But HOW should I use this `QGraphicsElliseItem`? The documentation says to add it to a `QGraphicsScene`. How to add a `QGraphicsScene` to my actual main `QWidget`? Can I do that directly? Or do I need to add THAT to something else? I need an example code!

Comment: @Alex: you are new to Qt, are you? QGraphicsView is an entirely different framework to QWidgets. You can do it either way; you could even do QML, but really, if you want to stick with QWidgets, you have to implement this yourself, sorry. That is just how it is, period. Get over it and do the stuff.

Comment: Yes, I am new to Qt (and often utterly confused) and I did not know that these are different frameworks. I can try using this other framework. In it, does `QGraphicsView` correspond to `QWidget`? Do they have similar methods? Can't you provide a simple example code-template so I see how to do it in principle?

Comment: @Alex: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/graphicsview.html But really, you are supposed to know more about the subject and not ask such broad questions further down the line.

Comment: I am sorry to set you up because of my lack of knowledge. If you have problems with people asking valid questions - maybe you  should do something else. Now I was able to run a simple example to draw a simple circle. So far so good. But my code was able to define a brush to fill the circle - on a black background! I know how this works for `QPainter` - but for the different framework I have to start from scratch in order to see where my brush fits in. But please do not worry: I will not ask how do this, I will spend the next hours or days to figure it out myself!

Comment: And the black background? And the brush filling?

Comment: @Alex: added the brush thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54389/discussion-between-alex-and-laszlo-papp).